# How to call C# function with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am beginning to learn ASP.NET and am attempting to check if a textbox is formatted properly.  I can check for proper format, but I don't know how to connect the cshtml in the frontend and the cs in the backend.  Below is my code from Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <h2>Robot Control Main Page</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
            <span>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="ipAddr" placeholder="IP Address">
                <input type="button" name="btn_confirm" value="Confirm" onclick="CheckValidIP()">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the function from my C# HomeController class.

```
//From my C# class
public ActionResult CheckValidIP()
{
    return View();
}
```

How do I connect the button click to the C# function and have that same C# function access the text variable input in the span?

Comment: You need to learn from the basic. Check this MS official link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: It doesn't work like that. MVC has different concept than WebForms. You could write JavaScript function to validate input in browser or do post the model to action and validate value in action. There is not easy way to tell what C# function to execute for input from cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is called "Remote Validation" in Asp.Net MVC.

**First** ensure that client validation is enable in your web.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

**Second** create in your controller the validation method that will return a JsonResult.

```
public class ValidationController : Controller 
{
    public JsonResult CheckValidIP(string clientIP) 
    {
        //your validation code here
        if (!_repository.AllowIp(clientIP))
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Third** in the model insert the `[Remote]` attribute. The first parameter is the `Action` and the second is the `Controller`.

```
public class CreateUserModel : EditUserModel {
    [Remote("CheckValidIP", "Validation")]
    public override string ClientIP { get; set; }
}
```

**Last** but not least, your have to use Html Helper to generate the html with javascript and so on.

```
@model RemoteValidation.Models.SampleModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Remote Validation</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientIp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientIp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientIp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a sample running application, with just the remote validation, here => https://github.com/ricardodemauro/AspNetMVCRemoteValidation

The RemoteAttribute class creates a string that represents the URL to use to invoke the server-based validation. The ASP.NET MVC framework then submits the JSON-encoded GET request for the URL. 
In this example, if the user enters "127.0.0.1" in the Client IP  text entry box, the client will request the following URL:
/Validation/CheckValidIP?ClientIP=127.0.0.1

Here you can find more detail information => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to do is rather exceptional and I would suggest you to learn how validation works in MVC. But if you must validate field on server you need to use remote validation which is explained here: [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx).